# How to pass URL in webservice

Tags: java, php

I want to pass this URL as a value in web address 
`http://localhost/h2orn/php/verify.php?email=$emails&hash=$hash` 
but, i can pass only before ampersand symbol.. I want to pass all the URL...

I'm using java webservice

code here:

$message ="http://localhost/h2orn/php/verify.php?email=$emails&hash=$hash\n\n";

$url = "http://localhost:8084/mail/webresources/EmailTest";

$mail = "toAddress=" . $emails . "&emailbody=" . $message;

Comment: Do you mean a web URL with a GET variable value and GET variable value is again a URL? The below is example. Refer to url GET variable. `https://www.google.ae/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F3684022%2Finclude-url-inside-url&ei=bbFJVbvKFY3XapDsgZAF&usg=AFQjCNGW85LznTVTBsmtMM6Nxrncv7YB2A&sig2=I-9SSV4B1adwNpRfTkr0Ag&bvm=bv.92291466,d.d2s`

Comment: **you can use `&amp;` instead of `&`**

Comment: No.. Its not working

Comment: example: $message ="http://localhost/h2orn/php/verify.php?email=$emails amp hash=$hash \n\n\n ";                                                                                                                    $url = "http://localhost:8084/mail/webresources/EmailTest";
 $mail = "toAddress=" . $emails . "&emailbody=" . $message;

Answer (score 1):

Try to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it before

From the documentation:

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a
>   query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next
>   page.

Answer (score 0):

```
- You can use &amp; instead of &.
```