# How to escape ampersand symbol

Tags: php

I want to escape ampersand symbol. because, it assume another parameter.. I want pass all this below message to java web service parameter.. That ampersand symbol cut the message.. Please anyone help

My php code:

```
$message ="Hi $names \r\n";

$message.="Welcome to Home 2 Office Rider Network. To activate your account \r\n";

$message.="please verify your email using below URL \r\n\n";

$message.="http://localhost/h2orn/php/verify.php?email=$emails&hash=$hash \n\n\n ";
    $message.="Thanks for your interest and support to H2ORN. Kindly reach out to \r\n";
    $message.="'care@h2orn.in' for any queries relating to H2ORN operations.\r\n\n\n";
    $message.="Thanks\r\n";
    $message.="Support Team\r\n\n\n";

$message.="This is automated email message. Please do not reply to this email.\r\n \n\n";

$url = "http://localhost:8084/mail/webresources/EmailTest";
$mail = "toAddress=" . $emails . "&emailbody=" . $message ;
$ch  = curl_init($url);
```

Thanks for advance,

Comment: It doesn't matter that the target service is written in Java, this has nothing to do with Java. I've removed the tag.

Comment: I've just noticed that you [asked this question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068893/how-to-pass-url-in-webservice) and [got the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30069229/157247). On Stack Overflow, it is **not** okay to repost the same question. If it was unclear to you how to use the answer, the way SO works, you'd comment on the answer saying that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *just* want to encode ampersands, you want to properly URI-encode all of the values. You do that with the [`urlencode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
$mail = "toAddress=" . urlencode($emails) . "&emailbody=" . urlencode($message) ;
//                     ^^^^^^^^^                            ^^^^^^^^^
```